# CodeIgniter - implode/query binding causing unwanted string

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have the following query attempting an update in CodeIgniter:

```
$sql = "UPDATE fanout.manual_data
                SET call_leader_id = ?
                WHERE id IN (?)";

$q = $this->db->query($sql, array($leaderID, implode(", ", $empIDs)));
```

The implode is creating a string of all the IDs in my array.  However, that is resulting in the query looking like:

```
UPDATE fanout.manual_data SET call_leader_id = '55993' WHERE id IN ('57232, 0097726, 0076034');
```

When what I need is:

```
UPDATE fanout.manual_data SET call_leader_id = '55993' WHERE id IN (57232, 0097726, 0076034);
```

Only difference, is the single quotes surrounding the string of IDs.  Is this something I need to do myself and skip over CI's query bindings (http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html) or is something CI can handle and I'm just missing a step?

Thanks.

Comment: Hey @Ryan can you tell me how you figured out that the variable was getting single quotes around it? Is there a php function that will output the ACTUAL query that was ran? I had a similar problem and if i would have been able to tell that single quotes were placed around my var it would have helped me tremendously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can skip that behavior. You're technically passing a string, so CI interprets it as such and simply surrounds it with quotes.

I think you're better off simply concatenating the `$empIDs` by hand (e.g. using a `foreach` loop), escaping them with `$this->db->escape()` in case you wanna be sure.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was thinking but wasn't sure.