# CodeIgniter Query Binding Using IN Clause with String array or string list

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Below is an example which fails.  I have tried several ways of getting $arrayOfIds below into the correct syntax for the id IN (?) with no luck.  If I do not query bind, it works.

**Note:** We are **not** using Active Record.

```
// this is actually being passed in as argument
$arrayOfIds = array('A0000-000000000001','B0000-000000000001','C0000-000000000001');  

$params = array();
array_push($params,1); // for the status
array_push($params, "'" . implode("','",$arrayOfIds) . "'"); // for the id in 

$sql = "SELECT name FROM my_table WHERE status = ? AND id IN (?) ";

$query = $this->db->query($sql,$params);
```

Comment: Have you tried dumping your query using $this->db->last_query() after it's run to see what the SQL looks like?

Comment: well, I suppose it is just a typo from copying to here, but you are using $arrayOfIds above, then $companyEntityIds. Let's at least correct our post, then run $this->db->last_query() as Mathew Daly said

Comment: so, yo uedited your typo, but you didn't give us the useful info we need - what does your query now look like?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854710/codeigniter-implode-query-binding-causing-unwanted-string

Comment: Quick follow up dumping the last_query showed the error.  CI auto escapes bound query params. So was ending up with permutations like: IN ('\'A0000-000000000001,B0000-000000000001,C0000-000000000001'\'') -OR- ('\'A0000-000000000001\',\'B0000-000000000001\',\'C0000-000000000001\'').

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to build the `params` array differently and add as many question marks as the size of `arrayOfIds`.

EDIT:
The question marks are generated dynamically according to the array size.

```
$arrayOfIds = array('A0000-000000000001','B0000-000000000001','C0000-000000000001');  

$params = array();
array_push($params, 1);

$params = array_merge($params, $arrayOfIds);
$in_string = str_replace(' ', ',', trim(str_repeat("? ", count($arrayOfIds))));  

$sql = "SELECT name FROM my_table WHERE status = ? AND id IN (".$in_string.")";

$query = $this->db->query($sql, $params);
```

Comment: that's completely wrong. He is making his arrayOfIds into a single variable, and then trying to bind it. With your method, he would have to have a static number of array elements, which may not be true

Comment: Using his method Codeigniter is escaping the ticks making the query unusable. Using my answer, you can build the `IN (?,?,...)` with a simple loop over the array size.

Comment: This approach works very well and solved my problem. As noted in my comment above, CodeIgniter escapes each query bound item which is nice; however, leaves us this challenge when passing lists.  Your approach of creating a bind list variable for my list is great along with the merge to my params array.

Comment: you can also just tell it not to add the backticks

Comment: How can you do that and keep the query escaped?

Answer (score 1):

```
$arrayOfIds = array('A0000-000000000001','B0000-000000000001','C0000-000000000001');  

$status = 1;

$sql = "SELECT name FROM my_table WHERE status = ? AND id IN ?";

$query = $this->db->query($sql, array($status, $arrayOfIds));
```

Comment: Instead of just dumping some code, you should explain what this code does, how it's different from the original code and why it solves the problem.